# Convert ArrayList<String> to String[]

Tags: java, string, arraylist

How I can convert `ArrayList<String>` to `String[]`?
I'm tried to use this code:

```
ArrayList<String> al = getResources()...; //getting string-array from values.xml
String[] data = new String[al.size()];

for (int i = 0; i != al.size(); i++) {
    data[i] = al.get(i);
}
```

But it's very slow. How I can do it faster?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(String[]) al.toArray();` will do the trick.

Comment: Ejjectly.. Fast and Correct.

Comment: Wow... so many answers for that short time!

Answer (score 6):

Use [ArrayList.toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28%29) method to convert list of string to array of string.

Do like this

```
String[] data = al.toArray(new String[al.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
arraylist.toArray(array); // fill the array
```